# Solr. How to join two seperate queries

Tags: java, solr

I want to join two separate queries. And display information from them. First query is firms from *Canada*, second query is firms with name *Incremento*. So I need to run separate queries and join result information.

My schema is:

```
<entity name="firm" dataSource="jdbc" pk="id"
  query="select * from firm"
  deltaImportQuery="select * from firm where id='${dih.delta.id}'"
      deltaQuery="select id from firm where upd_date &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'">
    <field column="id" name="id"/>
    <field column="ADDRESS" name="address"/>
    <field column="EMPLOYEE" name="employee"/>
    <field column="NAME" name="name"/>
    <field column="VILLAGE" name="village"/>
    <field column="ZIPCODE" name="zipcode"/>
    <field column="PLACE" name="place"/>
    <entity name="country" pk="id"
    query="select country from country where id='${firm.country}'"
    deltaQuery="select id from country where upd_date > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
    parentDeltaQuery="select id from firm where country=${country.id}">
      <field column="country" name="countryName"/>
    </entity>
  </entity>
```

How to do that ???

Answer (score 0):

**Searching** :-

You can use e.g.

`q=name:incremento&fq=location:Canada` - Searches firms with name Incremento only in firms with location Canada

`fq=location:Canada&fq=name:Incremento` - Filters firms with Location CANADA and name Incremento

**Indexing** :-
You can either handle it in the SQL Query by using OR for compaines from Canada and ones with name Incremento.
e.g. `SELECT * FROM FIRMS WHERE COUNTRY='CANADA' OR NAME='INCREMENTO'`

OR DIH allows only  tag. you may have multiple root  tags. e.g.

```
<dataSource driver="..." url="..." user=".." />
    <document name="companies">
        <entity name="firm_canada" dataSource="jdbc" pk="id"
          query="select * from firm"
          deltaImportQuery="select * from firm where id='${dih.delta.id}'"
              deltaQuery="select id from firm where upd_date &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'">
            <field column="id" name="id"/>
            ....
        </entity>
        <entity name="firm_incremento" dataSource="jdbc" pk="id"
          query="select * from firm where ..."
          deltaImportQuery="select * from firm where id='${dih.delta.id}'"
              deltaQuery="select id from firm where upd_date &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'">
            <field column="id" name="id"/>
            ....
        </entity>       
    </document>
</dataSource>
```

Comment: You answered SQL query. But I whant to know how to do that in Solr Query like:

/select?q=lastname@gmail&qf=id+firstName+lastName+email&defType=edismax&debugQuery=true

????